# For Loop Filter on Pandas DataFrame not Working

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, dataframe, filter

I have a very simple for loop :

```
## Keep or Drop Rows from Ad Servers

dataframes = [atlas_df, flashtalking_df, innovid_df, ias_viewability_df, ias_fraud_df]

for df in dataframes:
    df = df[df['Placement Name'].str.contains("»")]
```

when I run the for loop though, nothing filters.

However, if I write it down manually as:

```
ias_fraud_df = ias_fraud_df[ias_fraud_df['Placement Name'].str.contains("»")]
```

The filter works.

Any ideas on what I am missing?

Comment: I test it by doing a simple count of the df lines.

For eg.  when I apply the for loop to `ias_fraud_df` and do `ias_fraud_df.count()` the number of lines is the same.

If I apply it manually, then the number of lines changes to the correct number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're working on the iterator, you need to reference the original df by using an index into the list:

```
for i in range(len(dataframes)):
    df = dataframes[i]    
    dataframes[i] = df[df['Placement Name'].str.contains("»")]
```

This is so the original df in the list is modified

Example:

```
In [108]:
l = list('abcd')
for i in range(len(l)):
    l[i] = 'new_' + l[i]

Out[108]:
['new_a', 'new_b', 'new_c', 'new_d']
```

Versus:

```
In [110]:
l = list('abcd')
for x in l:
    x = 'new_' + x
l

Out[110]:
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

So you see that the latter which is semantically the same as your code never modifies the original elements in the list whilst the other does

Comment: I just tested the example you provide and it works perfectly. However when I apply the code for my exact examples, it stills doesn't filter

Comment: Then you may have some data integrity issues that we can't reproduce unless you post raw data and code. I'd test in your loop that your filtering actually produces a df

Comment: I double checked, so it works perfectly, but the new dataframe, instead of being called, for e.g. `ias_viewability_df`, has to be recalled as `dataframes[3]`. 

Is there any way to rename `dataframe[3]` to `ias_viewability_df` automatically? And accordingly, match all the remaining `dfs` to their `dataframes` list?

Comment: no, for that you'd need a dict where the key is the string name of your df, and the values being your df if you want that kind of behaviour

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprehension - output is list of filtered `Dataframes`:

```
dataframes = [df[df['Placement Name'].str.contains(u"»")] for df in dataframes]
```

Sample:

```
atlas_df = pd.DataFrame({'Placement Name':['deu_gathf»', 'deu_gahf', 'fra_gagg'],
                         'another_col':[1,2,3]})
flashtalking_df = pd.DataFrame({'Placement Name':['deu_gahf»','fra_ga', 'deu_gatt'],
                         'another_col':[4,5,6]})

dataframes = [atlas_df, flashtalking_df]
print (dataframes)
[  Placement Name  another_col
0     deu_gathf»            1
1       deu_gahf            2
2       fra_gagg            3,   Placement Name  another_col
0      deu_gahf»            4
1         fra_ga            5
2       deu_gatt            6]

dataframes = [df[df['Placement Name'].str.contains(u"»")] for df in dataframes]
print (dataframes)
[  Placement Name  another_col
0     deu_gathf»            1,   Placement Name  another_col
0      deu_gahf»            4]
```

Comment: Who was the guy looking for canonical answers?